# How do I assign values to an array within a typdef structure in C?

Tags: c, typedef

I am trying to assign values to an array within a typedef struct and continually am getting an syntax error.

```
Error expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '.' token
```

Here is my code:

```
myfile.h

#define  Digit12  0x00u
#define  Digit34  0x01u
#define  Digit56  0x01u

typedef struct
{
   uint8_t trData[3]; 
} CImageVersion;

myfile.c

CImageVersion oImageVersion; // declare an instance

oImageVersion.trData = { Digit12, Digit34, Digit56};
```

Later on in the code

```
otherfile.c

extern CImageVersion oImageVersion;
```

An arry is a pointer but if i change the assignment to

```
oImageVersion->trData = { Digit12, Digit34, Digit56};
```

I get the same error. I am very confused as to what I am doing wrong The error is pointing to directly after the oImageVersion when I assign the values

Comment: You can't assign to an array. Only initialize it on definition or copy to it.

Comment: Try `CImageVersion oImageVersion; // declare an instance

oImageVersion.trData = { Digit12, Digit34, Digit56};` --> `CImageVersion oImageVersion  = { {Digit12, Digit34, Digit56} };`

Comment: Also, `->` is for pointers to structures. Actual structures use `.`

Comment: Rather than assign the array, assign the structure: `oImageVersion = (CImageVersion) { {Digit12, Digit34, Digit56}  };`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't assign directly to an array.  The syntax you're using is only valid when a variable is *defined*.  I.e. you can do this:

```
CImageVersion oImageVersion = { { Digit12, Digit34, Digit56} };
```

But not this:

```
CImageVersion oImageVersion;
oImageVersion.trData = { Digit12, Digit34, Digit56};
```

If you don't assign the values when the variable is defined, you need to assign to each array element individually:

```
oImageVersion.trData[0] = Digit12;
oImageVersion.trData[1] = Digit34;
oImageVersion.trData[2] = Digit56;
```